# Como mudar a posição do controle do video?

Tags: css, html5

Para caber o video na tela de uma aplicação mobile, fiz o sequinte, coloquei o `width` do video do tamanho da tela, coloquei `margin-top` negativo pela metadade do que sobrou do container para ajustar o centro, e botei um `overflow: hidden` para não aparecer o restante do vídeo, irá cortar o vídeo um pouco, ou muito, mas não tem problema. Alias o unico problema é que o controle do video fica embaixo, e como cortei parte dele, então não aparece:

```html
<div style="height: 500px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 375px; border-style: dashed">
    <video controls src= "https://d2rrsmhcfsezix.cloudfront.net/videos/_fa9421ef08f88170ac649e3c89bf39861833e473.mp4" style="margin-top: -120px; position: absolute; width: 100%">

    </video>
  </div>
```

Para mostrar os controle basta tirar o overflow, mas aí o vídeo estrapola a tela predefinida.

```html
<div style="height: 500px; position: relative; width: 375px; border-style: dashed">
    <video controls src= "https://d2rrsmhcfsezix.cloudfront.net/videos/_fa9421ef08f88170ac649e3c89bf39861833e473.mp4" style="margin-top: -120px; position: absolute; width: 100%">

    </video>
  </div>
```

Existe alguma forma de mudar a posição do controle do vídeo, por exemplo para respeitar o `bottom` do container pai?

Comment: Se vc quiser refazer o player aqui tem um artigo bem interessante https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html

Comment: Não pode cortar a parte de cima do vídeo e mostrar os controles?

Comment: Outra coisa: por que vc não ajusta o vídeo todo dentro da área, sem fazer cortes?

Comment: A ídeia e centralizar o video na tela, se eu cortar só de cima, irá ficar esquisito. Se eu não fazer os cortes e centralizar vai ficar lados brancos do lado, que em questão de Desgin, pelo menos eu acho, vai ficar pior visualmente.

Comment: Vc poderia ajustar o vídeo dentro da div e colocar um fundo na div para não ficar os lados em branco. Tipo como o Youtube faz quando a largura do vídeo é menor que a área. Talvez um fundo preto ou cinza escuro.